# OpenGL Ubuntu Depth

Tags: c, ubuntu, opengl

I'm writing a simple OpenGL program on Ubuntu which draws two square (one in front of the other) using vertex array. For some reason, the GL_DEPTH_TEST does not seem to work. The object in the back appear in front of the one in the front. Depth buffer is enabled by

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
```

GL_DEPTH_TEST is enabled by

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

and depth buffer is cleared before drawing by

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

The complete code is shown below:

```
#define BUFFER_OFFSET( offset )   ((GLvoid*) (offset))

#define NUM_VERTICES 8

vec4 vertices[8] =
{{0.0, 0.0, -0.25, 1.0},    // front
 {0.0, 0.5, -0.25, 1.0},
 {0.5, 0.5, -0.25, 1.0},
 {0.5, 0.0, -0.25, 1.0}, 
 {0.25, 0.25, -0.75, 1.0},  // back
 {0.25, 0.75, -0.75, 1.0},
 {0.75, 0.75, -0.75, 1.0},
 {0.75, 0.25, -0.75, 1.0}};

vec4 vertex_colors[8] =
{{1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},  // red
 {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
 {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
 {1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0},
 {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0},  // green
 {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0},
 {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0},
 {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0}};

void init(void)
{
    GLuint program = initShader("vshader_td.glsl", "fshader_td.glsl");
    glUseProgram(program);

    GLuint vao;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    GLuint buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices) + sizeof(vertex_colors), NULL, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), sizeof(vertex_colors), vertex_colors);

    GLuint vPosition = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vPosition, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

    GLuint vColor = glGetAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(vColor);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(points)));

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, NUM_VERTICES);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(512, 512);
    glutCreateWindow("Test Depth");
    glewInit();
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

The vertex shader is shown below:
    #version 130

```
in vec4 vPosition;
in vec4 vColor;
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vColor;
    gl_Position = vPosition;
}
```

and the fragment shader is shown below:
    #version 130

```
in vec4 color;
out vec4 fColor;

void main()
{
    fColor = color;
}
```

Why object in the front is blocked by the object in the back?

Comment: Try to simplify. Find other things to remove. You were quite successful already, I admit. (Maybe shaders.) Find something which works, maybe from a tutorial. Work both towards each other. I.e. make the tutorial more like your code and your code more like the tutorial. Do so even for the "obvious" things. You can also try to make a [mcve] for posting here, you can assume that the readers (e.g. me) have OpenGL, glew, glut etc. installed as useable libs, but everythign else needs to be in what you post and in a convenient shape (i.e. one code quote, instead of several pieces.)

Comment: glVertexAttribPointer(vColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(sizeof(points))); <== why sizeof(points) and not just 0?  If you'd post an [mcve], then I could find out for myself, but you didn't." Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."

Comment: also, I don't see GL_QUADS as a valid option to https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml but you didn't tell us what version of opengl you are using, either...

Comment: I've no idea why this question was closed, the mistake is easy to spot. What you marked as "front" actually lies behind what you marked as "back". I don't know how you came to the assumption that it should be the other way round, I can only guess that you confused this with classical, left-handed OpenGL eye space convention where the "camera: looks into `-z` direction - but that is totally irrelevant here, since you never established an eye space at all, and draw directly in clip space instead.

Answer (score 0):

In the vertex shader, you do

> ```
> in vec4 vPosition;
> [....]
> gl_Position = vPosition;
> ```

without applying any transformations. Since `gl_Position` is the *clip space* position of the vertex, this means that your vertex coordinates are interpreted as being specified in clip space.

And your vertex coordinates

> ```
> vec4 vertices[8] =
> {{0.0, 0.0, -0.25, 1.0},    // front
>  [...]
>  {0.25, 0.25, -0.75, 1.0},  // back
> ```

just imply that the points you marked as "front" lie *behind* the ones you marked as "back".

I don't know how you came to the assumption that it should be the other way round, I can only guess that you confused this with classical, left-handed OpenGL eye space convention where the "camera: looks into -z direction - but that is totally irrelevant here, since you never established an eye space at all, and draw directly in clip space.